# Как убрать пустую область слева и справа от заголовка ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

При разработке обычных десктопных приложений (на WPF), никогда не обращал внимание на специфическую отрисовку заголовка `ListView`.

Области выделены красным.

[image: выделение отрисовки заголовка ListView]

Но тут возникла необходимость делать дополнительное окно, на которое выводятся `ListView` с 2-мя колонками.
С этого окна, захватывается изображение попиксельно, специальным устройством и отправляются на светодиодные табло, и все мелкие детали там хорошо видны.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListHeaderStyle8X2" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Border
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="ContentHeader"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            Padding="5,5,5,0"
                            Background="Chartreuse"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            TextAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <ListView Name="Table8X21" Background="DarkCyan">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListHeaderStyle8X2}">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Номер">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TicketName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Касса">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CashierName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Попробуйте к вашему Border в стиле добавить Margin="-3, 0"

Comment: Работает, спасибо, а откуда такой костыль, почему именно -3 ? Императивно подобрано)

Comment: вроде как,  при использовании View в listView как контейнера элементов определяется ItemsContainer у которого автоматически выставляется Padding как 3, собственно от сюда и Margin="-3, 0"

Comment: Может замечали, при работе с Label такая ерунда

Comment: ага, понятно)) спасибо большое

Comment: Забыл добавить. Это способ касается только заголовка - элементы в это колонке останутся сдвинутыми. Если нужно что бы и элементы тоже сдвинулись добавьте в стиль: <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-3, 0" />

Comment: если это все, отмечу как ответ

Comment: @TomDugger, у Label-то понятно, там в Live Property Explorer прямо видно Padding="5,5,5,5". А здесь я что-то не смог найти...

Comment: у label - это значение по умолчанию, а ItemsContainer используется в шаблонах и обычно не привязывается к какому либо свойству, т.к. может содержатся в любом контроле с элементами для отображения, который может не содержать Padding

Comment: @TomDugger, вы предлагаете подавить отступ противоположным значением в дочернем элементе. Но было бы неплохо найти то место где этот отступ задается и установить именно там нулевое значение...

Comment: @Андрей, придется переопределять шаблон ListView

Comment: @Aldmi, попробуйте у ListView установить свойство BorderThickness равным 0

Comment: BorderThickness равным 0, не помогло

Answer (score 10):

Как верно заметили в комментариях, отступы в заголовке составляют 3 пикселя, но добавлять отрицательный отступ к `GridViewColumnHeader` неправильно, т. к. этот отступ будет у *каждого* столбца (т.е. столбцы будут перекрывать друг друга), а нам нужно устранить только отступ слева и справа у всей строки заголовка.

Покопавшись, с помощью встроенных в Visual Studio инструментов Live Visual Tree и Live Property Explorer, в визуальном дереве окна, я выяснил, что из этих трех пикселей два дает `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter.Margin` и один — `ListBoxChrome.BorderThickness`.

С `ListBoxChrome.BorderThickness` всё просто — он привязан к `BorderThickness` родителя, т. е. самого `ListView` и устраняется просто в разметке или стиле:

```
<ListView Name="Table8X21" ... BorderThickness="0">
```

Также в Live Visual Tree видно, что `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` лежит внутри `ScrollViewer`, открыв стандартный стиль `ListView`, можно найти только один `ScrollViewer`, у которого стиль задается вот так:

```
<ScrollViewer ... Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}">
```

Этот стиль можно найти в документации Microsoft [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates#listview-controltemplate-examples).

В этом стиле внутри шаблона можно увидеть такой фрагмент:

```
<GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Margin="2,0,2,0" ...
```

Это и есть те два пикселя слева и справа.

Наиболее простым решением видится скопировать этот стиль из документации целиком и добавить в ресурсы своего окна (или куда вам удобнее), а затем просто в нем убрать этот `Margin`. В итоге ресурс с ключом `GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey` будет перекрыт и будет использоваться локальный.

В итоге у меня получилось вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Заголовки `GridView` помещены в элемент `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter`, у которого в шаблоне по умолчанию задан `Margin = 2` с правой и левой стороны. Можно обработать у `Border` заголовка событие `Loaded`

```
<Border        
   Loaded="Border_Loaded"
   ... />
```

и переопределить его:

```
private void Border_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     FrameworkElement p1 = (FrameworkElement)(((FrameworkElement)sender).TemplatedParent); // GridViewColumnHeader
     FrameworkElement p2 = (FrameworkElement)p1.Parent; // GridViewHeaderRowPresenter           
     p2.Margin = new Thickness(0);
}
```

Comment: Хм, может не сработать в общем случае, если изменен шаблон. Лучше уж тогда воспользоваться `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()` (в цикле, пока не найдется родитель соответствующего типа). Минус еще — ваш код будет срабатывать для каждого столбца.

Comment: @АндрейNOP В стандартных темах структура этой части шаблона ListView одинаковая, отличаются только значения, по крайней мере в Aero, Luna и Classic. (Кстати, ненулевой Margin у этого элемента только в Aero.) Но в нестандартных темах да, может слететь.

Comment: По моему ресурс `GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey` вообще от темы не зависит, поэтому `Margin="2,0,2,0"` во всех будет. Но я не про темы говорю, а про шаблоны вообще. Если ТС или кто еще изменит шаблон контрола, то ваш код перестанет работать, поэтому лучше искать нужного родите на любом уровне вложенности, а не только на конкретном

Comment: @АндрейNOP Как ни странно, зависит. Если принудительно включить луну (`<ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Luna;component/themes/Luna.NormalColor.xaml" />`), Margin будет нулевой.